# Avoiding iCloud conflicts with non CoreData app

Tags: ios, macos, sqlite, icloud

I am working on a non CoreData based app (sqlite), now that it must be ported to iPad, all hell has broken loose.

Since syncing is not needed, I am trying to stay with my good old sqlite solution. However I have noticed that even now I have an ugly problem: if the same app is used by the same user in different devices. The database file is automatically backed up to iCloud, but now more than one device want to upload different databases into the same location.

Which one is the common solution to this problem? My immediate guess is saving the database into a subfolder like .../Documents/**some_type_of_id**/ and use iCloud to backup different databases and settings for each device.

How should I generate that ID? My first choice seems to be this:

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]
```

However, now that I am getting my hands dirty, I am wondering which equivalent solution should be used with a Mac app (same iCloud user on different macs). UIDevice is not within the Mac SDK.

How should I generate a Mac unique ID?

Although I am asking now about UIDs, my first concern is still avoiding iCloud conflicts. I would appreciate any guidance or references to how properly handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate UDID like this.

```
  CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
  NSString * uuidString = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
  CFRelease(newUniqueId);
```

Hope it helps.